# Let $K$ be a field containing an integral domain $D$ and $F$ be the field of quotients of $D$. Then $K$ contains a field isomorphic to $F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, soft-question, alternative-proof

> Let $K$ be a field containing an integral domain $D$ and $F$ be the
>   field of quotients of $D$. Then $K$ contains a field isomorphic to
>   $F$.

I have looked over some solutions but I don’t understand the general approach. That is, they start by defining a map $\phi:F \to K$, and show $\phi$ is an isomorphism. I understand what follows after that, but I am having trouble with the start of this approach.

Now, the main point of this problem is to show that $F$ is the smallest field containing D. And proving these kinds of problems involves assuming any field containing $F$ will be isomorphic to $F$ meaning that we can’t reduce $F$ any further.

Keeping this in mind, I am struggling with the following questions:

- Why does the approach highlighted above make sense?
- Why even phrase the question like this if we aren’t going to show an imaginary sub-field of $K$ and show it to be isomorphic to $F$?
- Is it possible to construct a proof with the following outline:

Let $F’$ be a field s.t. $F’ \subset K$, then show $F \cong F’$.

Comment: I think I understand the general approach for the proof. If we show $K \cong F$ then we have shown $K$ is pretty much “equalish” to $F$ and it can’t be reduced any further if we are to preserve ring isomorphism. So, this proof effectively proves $F$ is the smallest field containing $D$. Am I right? 

I am mainly curious if we can simply construct a proof in the way the question is phrased.

Comment: $\phi$ is not an isomorphism necessarily, but it is enough to construct a homomorphism of fields, since all homomorphisms of fields are injective, and then $\phi$ is an isomorphism onto some subfield  of $K$.

Answer (score 1):

$F$ is the smallest field that $D$ can be embedded in.  The field of fractions has the universal property that any embedding of an integral domain $D$ into a field $K$ extends to an embedding of $F$.

Comment: At this point I haven’t been introduced to that universal property you are talking about. So I need to prove it without using this property. The only tools it seems I have on my disposal are ring homomorphism and fundamental properties of integral domain, field and ring.

Comment: Since $\Bbb K$ is a field, for every $d\in D$, $d^{-1}\in \Bbb K$.  That is, $d$ is a unit.  It follows that $\Bbb K$ contains all fractions of elements of $D$.  But that's a field, namely $\Bbb F$.